# var vs this vs $scope in AngularJS (1.4)

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am learning angular and have lost my mind understanding the difference between **'var'**, **'this'** and **'$scope'**.
Although I read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers) but it went above my head.
When I use `ng-controller="myController as ctrl"` , I only have access to the variables and function set on **this**.
Whereas defining `ng-controller="myController"`  I only have access to variables and function set on **$scope**.
Can some one please explain this topic in depth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `var` is pure javascript and is just how you declare variables in javascript. Like so:

```
var myName = 'Nikolaj';
var myAge = 1700;
// etc.
```

If you're unfamiliar with `var` you should start by learning Javascript before venturing into Angular, since the learning curve of Angular can be quite steep.

With that said I'll try to explain the other concepts.

**Using controllerAs**

When using the recommended controllerAs syntax, you get a reference to the controller instance in your template. This is what happens when you use `<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl"></div>`;

Your controller is basically "newed" and stored in a variable called `ctrl` which is made available in the template by angular. This allows you to access your controller members (public functions and variables) in the template like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <p>{{ctrl.name}}</p>
</div>
```

In order for the variable `name` to be available in the template, it must first be declared as a public member/variable of your controller. That is where the `this`-keyword comes into play. When you create your controller, to make the variable `name` public, you'd do it like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController', function(){
    this.name = 'My name variable';
});
```

Here `this` is a special concept in Javascript that is a reference to the function context - but just basic Javascript.

**Using $scope**

When you instead use your controller like this: `<div ng-controller="myController"></div>` you don't have direct access to the controller instance in your template. Instead, every time you use something in an Angular expression, for instance `{{name}}`, Angular implicitly assumes the variable `name` exists on the $scope variable. Each controller has a $scope variable associated with it when it is linked to the template. To access this variable inside your controller body, you'll access it like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'My name variable';
});
```

---

The reason why the **controllerAs** syntax is recommended, is in part because when using $scope, it can be difficult to determine which scope you're referring to when you have multiple nested scopes (i.e. nested controller). As in this example:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <h1>{{firstControllerVariable}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="SecondController">
        <h2>{{whereDoIBelong}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the controllerAs syntax, it is pretty clear which variable belongs to which controller:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController as first">
    <h1>{{first.firstControllerVariable}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="SecondController as second">
        <h2>{{second.iKnowWhereIBelong}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another reason to use the controllerAs syntax is because it'll make it easier to migrate to ES2016 and above.

Comment: So if I am not wrong, using **controllerAs**  syntax allows us to introduce a new namespace bound to our controller without the need to put scope properties in an additional object literal?

Comment: It isn't as much a new namespace being bound to the controller, as it is a reference to the controller instance itself. You can imagine it working kinda like this: `var ctrl = new myController()` behind the scenes.